# How to multi-thread python function that has requires calling multiple other functions

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

I want to multi-thread a python script in my main function that calls many other previously defined functions. My understanding is that if one function needs to be ran before another function is called (i.e. in sequence) then you cannot multi thread the functions since the latter function requires the output from the prior function. Is this correct?

For a function that does not require the value from a previously called function I want to multi-thread the functions.

Example

```
def main():

    df = pd.read_csv(path) # I don't believe this code can be parallelized with the code below since this needs to be executed first

    # I want to parallelize this code below
    for col in df[[i for i in df.columns if i.endswith('col1')].columns:
        df = function1(df, col, 4, 1)

    df = function2(df, [i for i in df.columns if i.endswith('col2')], 2, 6)

    for col in [i for i in df.columns if i.endswith('col2')]:
        df = pd.merge_asof(df, function3(df[col], 9), left_index=True, right_index=True)

    for i in [i for i in df.columns if i.endswith('col3')]:
        df = function4(df, col)
```

Right now when I use the following code below the performance does not increase at all.

```
with Pool() as p:
    p.starmap(main, [(inputs...)])
    end_time = time.time()
    print(end_time - start_time)
    print('Script took:', end_time - start_time)
```

I also tried this and no success with performance increase.

```
with Pool() as p:
    p.map(main, [inputs...)])
    end_time = time.time()
    print(end_time - start_time)
    print('Script took:', end_time - start_time)
```

Comment: It isn't supposed to. Multithreading pandas dataframes is an antipattern. Look at chunk-wise, or distributed processing with [dask](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/)

Comment: If you look at my comments I state that I want to parallelize the code below pd.read_csv(). Using dask in my case does slightly speed up the process for reading the file, but reading the file is not the major issue that is causing the script to take so long since the file is not very large. What is computationally expensive is creating features using the functions I've shown above (function1, function2, function3). Pandas reads the dataframe in about half a second so that is not a major issue. I want to parallelize the code below pd.read_csv().

Comment: Dask doesn't _just_ speed up reading from CSVs... you can parallelise the rest of your code.

Comment: You can also do that with pythons multiprocessing library. My understanding is dask was particularly amazing for parallelizing big data through a cluster of servers while also being able to do it on a single machine. If I had already written all my code it would be sort of a pain to completely re-write everything to be compatible with dask. I am running on a single machine, not a cluster of servers. I think multiprocessing python library should suffice for my needs.